# How to set Z transparency in Blender nodes using the Blender's Render?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

The context is like this: If you are using the Blender internal (Blender Render Machine) and you are also using nodes, and want to fine tune the transparency by using the Z Transparency value how should you proceed to achieve such setup?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the alpha input on the output node.
[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you but it doesn't work for me. Maybe because of my hardware? Could you provide a .blend?